# Show recyclerview after full download

Tags: android, firebase

I'am using Firebase

I have adapter with Glide and text

How show RecyclerView only after full download ?

I need it because firstly my app load text and about 2 second later start changing image in view

In addition some users have differents internet speed

".getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener" works with text after with image

".postDelay" is bad idea because different internet speed

Comment: are you using `DownloadManager` ?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, In the Layout Resource file, Set the visibility of `RecyclerView` to `GONE`. And as soon as download is complete, set that visibility to `VISIBLE` in your java file.

As you've tagged `Firebase` in your question. It can be possible that you are trying to say that you are using a `ValueEventListener` in your code, so you can set visibility of `RecyclerView` in that `ValueEventListener`.

To set visibility in `xml` file use this attribute:

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

To set visibility in `java` file use this code:

```
findViewById("recycler_view").setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```